# Perfect procedure for MySQL migration?

Tags: mysql, linux, database-migration

I would like to follow these steps for migration from one MySQL server to another:

Step 1: Perform a MySQL Dump

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt [database name] > [database name].sql
```

Step 2: Copy the Database using scp

```
scp [database name].sql [username]@[servername]:path/to/database/
```

step 3: Import the Database

```
mysql -u root -p newdatabase < /path/to/newdatabase.sql
```

but the question i have is, does that dump create all the users and privs ?
as per my knowledge, it should.

Please suggest/correct me if you have any better procedure

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But only if you use the correct mysqldump parameters. See this: [How to backup whole MySQL database with all users and permissions and passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848189/how-to-backup-whole-mysql-database-with-all-users-and-permissions-and-passwords)